Is it possible to add cached hashCode method to primitive string?
I have some methods that depend on hash code, like custom unique and hash collections in JS.
Since strings in JS are immutable and hash code is costly operation it make sense to cache it, unfortunately it's  impossible to set property on string so code below won't work.
I wonder if there's some way to make it work, maybe some hidden built-in "foo".builtInHashCode() function?
function calculateStringHashCode(s) {
  console.log("Calculating hash code for", s)
  return s.length
}

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  return this.cachedHashCode ??= calculateStringHashCode(this)
}

const s = "foo"
console.log(s.hashCode())
console.log(s.hashCode())

UPDATE, or (thanks to @guriev for suggestion) maybe using external cache, something like non working code below, but unfortunately WeakMap doesn't accept primitives as a key.
declare global {
  interface String {
    hashCode(): number
  }
}

const hashes = new WeakMap<string, number>() // <= Error primitives can't be keys
String.prototype.hashCode = function (this: string): number {
  let hash = hashes.get(this)
  if (hash == undefined) {
    console.log('calculating hash')
    hash = this.length // complex calculation of hash
    hashes.set(this, hash)
  }
  return hash
}

console.log('hi'.hashCode())
console.log('hi'.hashCode())


Why does it have to be attached to strings? Make a memoized hash code function. Maybe do something to keep the cache from ever growing if it's going to be long lived.

@VLAZ yes, memoization also possible, in such case String.prototype.hashCode will be just a wrapper calling the standalone cashe.

The problem is not the immutability of strings, but the way prototypes work. I propose to use this variant:
function calculateStringHashCode(s) {
  console.log("Calculating hash code for", s)
  return s.length
}

String.prototype.cachedHashCodes = { }

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  return this.cachedHashCodes[this] ??=calculateStringHashCode(this)
}

const s = "foo"
const t = "bar"
console.log(s.hashCode())
console.log(s.hashCode())
console.log(t.hashCode())
console.log(s.hashCode())
console.log(t.hashCode())

The idea is to store an immutable reference to a hash object in the prototype, to which to add values for each string.

cachedHashCodes doesn't need to exist on the prototype. It could be a free variable, as well, thus not potentially breaking any other functionality.

Yes. It would be even better from an encapsulation standpoint

Then even even better if hashCode isn't added to the prototype. And we're back to memoization

I think everyone here can write the function getMemoHash: (val: str) => str, but we are discussing inheritance and prototypes here.

Yes, also everybody can use a screwdriver. But we normally don't discuss how to use a hammer to take a screw out. This is simply an XY problem. And if you really think it's about prototypes, there are a bajillion dupes of how those work.

Thanks, I was thinking something similar, maybe with WeakMap

@AlexCraft WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO DO?! You can't use a WeakMap with primitives. And you're just dancing around memoization again. It feels like you're trying hard to avoid using a screwdriver. Or calling it such.

@VLAZ yes you are right, attaching it to String.prototype more like syntactical sugar. But the memoization is problematic too, as you can't use WeakMap to memo it. To avoid memory leaks.

@AlexCraft Other than proving the answerer wrong that "we are discussing inheritance and prototypes here" I still don't know what you want here. Now it's about WeakMaps. Which wasn't the case at first. It never needed to be the case. You keep coming up with Ys but not the X. I can only somewhat guess you're trying to ask about how to define an eviction policy for the cache. But you didn't ask for that.
